# How can i load information from a txt file to show on a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

So i am using this method to save data into a txt file :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter("test1.txt"))
        {
            objWriter.Write(textBox1.Text);
            objWriter.Write(textBox2.Text);
            objWriter.Write(comboBox1.Text);
            objWriter.Write(comboBox2.Text);

            MessageBox.Show("Details have been saved");
        }
    }
```

all those textbox and combobox are in a form called NewAppointment. And this is the panel in my MainForm:

```
private void panelDailyView_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int paintWidth = panelDailyView.ClientRectangle.Size.Width - vScrollBar.Width;
        int paintHeight = panelDailyView.ClientRectangle.Size.Height;
        int displayedRowCount = paintHeight / PanelRowHeight;
        int panelTopRow;
        int nextRow;
        int apptStartRow;
        int apptLength;
        string dispTime; 

        Font font = new Font("Arial", 10);
        Brush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkBlue);
        Brush appointmentBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue);

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        // Fill the background of the panel
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Linen), 0, 0, paintWidth, paintHeight);
        panelTopRow = vScrollBar.Value;
        if (_SelectedRow >= panelTopRow &&
            _SelectedRow <= panelTopRow + displayedRowCount)
        {
            // If the selected time is displayed, mark it
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.DarkKhaki), 
                            0, 
                            (_SelectedRow - panelTopRow) * PanelRowHeight,
                            paintWidth,
                            PanelRowHeight);
        }
        // Display the times at the start of the rows and
        // the lines separating the rows
        nextRow = panelTopRow;
        for (int i = 0; i <= displayedRowCount; i++)
        {
            dispTime = (nextRow / 2).ToString("0#") + (nextRow % 2 == 0 ? ":00" : ":30");
            nextRow++;
            g.DrawString(dispTime, font, drawBrush, 2, (i * PanelRowHeight + 4));
            g.DrawLine(Pens.DarkBlue, 0, i * PanelRowHeight, paintWidth, i * PanelRowHeight);
        }
        // Now fill in the appointments
        foreach (IAppointment appointment in _TodaysAppointments)
        {
            apptStartRow = Utility.ConvertTimeToRow(appointment.Start);
            apptLength = Utility.ConvertLengthToRows(appointment.Length);
            // See if the appointment is inside the part of the day displayed on the panel
            if (((apptStartRow >= panelTopRow) && 
                 (apptStartRow <= panelTopRow + displayedRowCount)) ||
                (apptStartRow + apptLength > panelTopRow))
            {
                // Calculate the area of the panel occupied by
                // the appointment
                if (apptStartRow < panelTopRow)
                {
                    apptLength = apptLength - (panelTopRow - apptStartRow);
                    apptStartRow = panelTopRow;
                }
                int apptDispStart = (apptStartRow - panelTopRow) * PanelRowHeight;
                int apptDispLength = apptLength * PanelRowHeight;
                if (apptDispStart + apptDispLength > paintHeight)  
                {
                    apptDispLength = paintHeight - apptDispStart;
                }
                Rectangle apptRectangle = new Rectangle(ApptOffset,
                                                        apptDispStart,
                                                        paintWidth - (ApptOffset * 2),
                                                        apptDispLength);
                // Draw the block of light blue
                g.FillRectangle(appointmentBrush,
                                apptRectangle);
                // Draw the black line around it
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, apptRectangle);
                if (Utility.ConvertTimeToRow(appointment.Start) >= panelTopRow)
                {
                    // If the top line of the appointment is displayed,
                    // write out the subject and location.  Temporarily
                    // reduce the clip area for the graphics object to ensure
                    // that the text does not extend beyond the rectangle
                    Region oldClip = g.Clip;
                    g.Clip = new Region(apptRectangle);
                    g.DrawString(appointment.DisplayableDescription,
                                 font,
                                 drawBrush,
                                 ApptOffset + 6,
                                 apptDispStart + 4);
                    g.Clip = oldClip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All i want to do is to load all the information saved in that .txt file to the panel.

Comment: So where have you tried to do so? I fail to see anywhere you *read* the file.

Comment: that is what i am asking too. where exactly i have to read the file in the code? and then how to show it on the panel.

Answer (score 1):

```
// replace filepath below with filepath of your text file.
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt");
```

Once you have the `text` variable populated, you can do whatever you want with it.  Like add it to your panel.

```
// something like...
panel.Text = text;
```

You can also read each line of the text file into an array and do whatever you like with the array:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt");
```

Comment: can you please tell me exactly where do i put that piece of code in my code?

Comment: @ChristosSpanos Did you not write the code that you posted above in your question?  Can't you logically conclude where the code should go that reads the file?  I've given you enough to continue, it's up to you to figure out what to do with the information.

Comment: AND don't you think that you have to talk to me a little bit better? Is that the way you talk to anyone who ask you a question? Don't you think that i am new to programming? Talk a little bit better rude man!

Comment: @ChristosSpanos I'm very sorry if you took what I wrote as being rude.  However, my point still stands: You wrote the code, you should know where to add the code to read the text file.

Comment: @ChristosSpanos: I think he was actually very polite, considering that you clearly have no idea what you're doing. This is not meant to be an insult, unless insulting you helps you decide to learn enough that you will stop receiving such insults. It's obvious to anyone who understands the flow of the code you posted that you need to acquire the information before the information is required for display.

Comment: Ask yourself: if you were going to display the constant text "Christos", how would you do that? If you can't figure that out, then this is past your current level of understanding. You need to stop, and read some beginner's books on C# and on programming in general.